# npm command is not installing packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

yesterday I was trying to install `echarts-for-react` package from npm but it started throwing error:

[image]

to double check I also tried creating a react app but `create-react-app` was also throwing the same error:

[image]

I also tried reinstalling `node` but the error still persist could anyone help me resolve this error :) ?

Comment: Btw are you sing private artifactory like JFROG.? Where are you trying to install from? Error looks like you are trying to install from some private artifactory and not the public one and this package does not exist there hence throwing the error. to solve it first of all you need to add this package to your artifactory then you can install it.

Comment: You aren't using the standard NPM registry. You're using `packagecloud.io` which doesn't appear to have the package you want

Comment: @Phil so how can I solve it ?

Comment: Check you registry settings and change them if you're not meant to be using `packagecloud.io` ~ https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/registry

Comment: Contact with your team and ask them how we can add ` echarts-for-react` package into our private artifactory they will help you to add this package. once its been added you can simplly run the yarn/npm command `yarn add  echarts-for-react` and will work.

Comment: @Phil this worked for me : npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

Answer (score 1):

```bash
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

the above line of code worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Btw are you using private artifactory like JFROG.? Where are you trying to install from? Error looks like you are trying to install from some private artifactory and not the public one and this package does not exist there hence throwing the error. to solve it first of all you need to add this package to your central private artifactory then you can use yarn or npm to install it like any other package you do. in your root directory check the file like .npmrc or .yarnc to see what is your registry url. you will understand where you are trying to install it from. or if it is not set you can create an file .npmrc or .yarnc and set the public registry url. for npm

//.npmrc

`registry=http://registry.npmjs.org // or your private artifactory`

Comment: ughhh I don't know anything about JFROG. how can I solve it ?

Comment: do check with your team specifically to the person who is managing the infra/devops, at least with team who is managing the central repository on your network for adding any package to private artifactory, there must be people who knows it. i will be more than happy to help if you don't get any help you can call me on 8682847253.

Answer (score -1):

while installing any package if throughs any error use --force in the end of command that will install package force fully e.g : npm install echarts-for-react --force

For creating new app use => npx create-react-app appName

Comment: I tried it and the error still persist.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).